# What is the difference += and +?

Tags: java

I was asked a question what the difference is between having `counter += 5` and `counter + 5` in the java programming language. I said they essentially do the same thing but I did not know how to explain why. I felt one was considered a shorthand representation of the same problem but now thinking about it more, I feel I am not correct. Can anyone give me a simple explanation the difference between them?

Comment: `counter += 5` <=> `counter = counter + 5` != `counter + 5`

Comment: One updates a variable and another does not, `counter += 5` is basically `counter = counter + 5`

Comment: Someone is yet to mention the keyword of interest here: _assignment_. Just look up assignment.

Comment: It was something I was asked a while ago. I understand they do the same thing but I felt there was more to it.

Comment: @MarcusBurkhart You're missing the point. They do not do the same thing.

Comment: Ok, I will look up assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`counter += 5` modifies `counter`. `counter += 5` can be used as a statement (e.g. line of code) on its own, because it does something (increments `counter` by 5).

`counter + 5` does not modify anything. `counter + 5` can only be used as an expression within a statement, because it doesn't do anything on its own.

Here is some code that demonstrates the difference:

```
int counter = 1;
System.out.println(counter + 5); // 6
System.out.println(counter); // 1
// counter + 5; // not a valid statement
counter += 5; // counter is now 6
System.out.println(counter); // 6
System.out.println(counter += 5); // 11
System.out.println(counter); // 11
```

Comment: `System.out.println(counter += 5);` Important to note that `counter` still updates even though the assignment is passed as an argument to a method.

Answer (score 3):

`counter += 5` is assigning the value of whatever counter was plus 5 to the counter variable while `counter+5` is return the result of 5 plus `counter` but the counter variable stays the same.

## += operator

For example you have a a variable counter that equals 3. When you do `counter += 5`, you are actually assigning a new value to the variable counter. so if counter was 5 and you do `counter+=3`, `counter` will now equal 8.

## + operator without the equal

In this case if your counter equals 3. when you do `counter+3` it will return 8 for that instance but your counter will still be 3.

## Code to demonstrate the differences:

```
int counter = 3;
counter += 5;
int y = 0;

/*this will return 8, since the result of 5 and counter was newly assigned to
 counter*/
System.out.println(counter);

//resetting counter value.
counter =3;
y = counter+5;

//here counter still remains at 3, because there wasn't anything assigned to it
System.out.println(counter);

//will return 8, because you assigned the result of counter and 5 to y. 
System.out.println(y);
```

Comment: not "adding 5 to counter" but rather adding 5 _and_ counter. Saying "_to_" is very confusing when we want to distinguish between assigning and not assigning.

Comment: Thanks. I was just missing the last part about updating the counter variable. I will accept answer in 10min

Comment: @MarcusBurkhart  "*I will accept answer in 10min*" Even though this answer is correct (only with the comment by keyser), you would usually want to wait to see if more answers crop up which are more satisfactory for you. Maybe they are more comprehensive, have code examples etc. It's just a suggestion of course.

Comment: @MarcusBurkhart you should've accepted my answer, Tim S already has enough points !! :)

Answer (score 1):

Only the JLS holds the true answer!

(Assuming `count` is a numeric type. If it's a `String`, for example, then everything everyone told you above is wrong at the time I wrote this.)

**+= operator**

> JLS 15.26.2 Compound Assignment Operators:
>
> > A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent to E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1 is evaluated only once.

following,

> > [...] the saved value of the **left-hand variable and the value of the right-hand operand are used to perform the binary operation indicated by the compound assignment operator**.
> >
> > [...] the result of the binary operation is converted to the type of the left-hand variable, subjected to value set conversion (§5.1.13) to the appropriate standard value set (not an extended-exponent value set), and **the result of the conversion is stored into the variable**.

(emphasis mine). In the above above notation, E1 and E2 will perform the operation indicated by += (meaning E1 + E2). The result is stored in E1.

**+ operator**

> JLS 15.18.2. Additive Operators (+ and -) for Numeric Types:
>
> > The binary + operator performs addition when applied to two operands of numeric type, producing the sum of the operands.

Note that there is no assignment here.

Answer (score 0):

`counter += 5` is the one that is shorthand, but it's shorthand for `counter = counter + 5`.  `counter + 5` is just an expression, what you get is a value that is 5 greater than the value of `counter`, but this value is just left behind and nothing is done with it.  In order for something else to happen, an additional operator needs to be present, such as the =, or assignment operator.  This operator takes an expression on the right hand side and an identifier on the left, evaluating the expression and assigning the result to the identifier.  Without assignment, values don't change, and even when you use methods that seem to change values without assignment (String.append() for example) there is an assignment hidden in the code of the function.  As an added fact, `counter += 5` can be reduced (if you really want to call it reducing it) to `counter++` used 5 times.